# Is there an equivalent of Sql Server's DateDiff('ms', d1, d2) in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, datediff

I am trying to fathom if it is possible to calculate the number of elapsed milliseconds between dates in Sqlite. ( `DateDiff('milliseconds', d1, d2)` in SQL Server)

There's a great example on how to do it for seconds [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but not for milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get there.

Given these 2 dates: `12:00:00:000 & 12:05:01:200`

```
( (
   (strftime('%M', EndDate) * 60) - 
   (strftime('%M', StartDate) * 60) 
  ) + 
  strftime('%f', EndDate) - 
  strftime('%f', StartDate)
) * 1000
```

results in a diff off 301200 (milliseconds)

The key is getting your head around the fact that `%f` yields seconds and milliseconds as a fraction of seconds (1.2), and you need to add that onto the total seconds in the minutes.